# OOP Proper use of interfaces in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, oop

I'm designing a framework and in the process I have come across an interesting but most likely basic problem. I have a base class called **CoreEngine** and two other classes that extend it: **CoreEngine1** and **CoreEngine2**. I created an interface that each of these classes would implement to increase the flexibility of my project. However, I have a problem... The definition of my methods in the interface do not match the definition in each inherited class! Each class must implement the following method:

**function get avatar():AvatarBase;**

The problem is that *CoreEngine1* and *CoreEngine2* expect a different type of avatar:

**CoreEngine1**

function get avatar():AvatarScaling

**CoreEngine2**

function get avatar():AvatarPlatform

As you can see, the return type for *avatar* in CoreEngine1 and CoreEngine2 do NOT match the type as specified in the interface. I was hoping that since both AvatarScaling and AvatarPlatform inherit **AvatarBase** that I wouldn't have a problem compiling. However, this is not the case. According to Adobe's documentation, the types MUST match the interface. I am trying to follow one of the core concepts of object oriented programming to extend the flexibility of my framework: "Program to an interface rather than an implementation". The first thing that comes to my mind is that the return type of the accessor method should be of an interface type (Maybe I just answered my own question).

I'm certain this is a common problem others have run into before. Architecturally, what do you think is the best way to solve this problem? Thanks in advance!

Regards,

Will

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you answered your own question... the return type would still be AvatarBase, you need to follow the signature that you specified in the interface... but you can technically return ANY descendent of AvatarBase in that function. So doing something like

```
return new AvatarScaling();
```

in CoreEngine1 would be perfectly acceptable.

Of course in your calling function you will get back an AvatarBase instance, and you will have to know what this is in order to cast to a specific subclass.

```
CoreEngine1 ce1 = new CoreEngine1();
AvatarScaling avatar = ce1.avatar() as AvatarScaling;
```

Comment: That code isn't AS3, you mean `var ce1:CoreEngine = new CoreEngine1(); var as:AvaterScaling = ce1.avatar() as AvatarScaling` or `(AvatarScaling)(ce1.avatar())` or `AvatarScaling(ce1.avatar());`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a limitation of how interfaces work and are declared.

If there's inheritance that can happen with the return types, as you've described with `AvatarBase` and subclasses, then I think the right approach is to make the return type the lowest common denominator and just handle the resulting object on the other end. So, if you're dealing with a `CoreEngine1` object, you know you can cast the result from `AvatarBase` to `AvatarScaling`. Alternately, if you don't know the object type that you are calling `get avatar()` on, then you can type check the returned value. The type check would then only be needed if you're looking to call a method that exists on `AvatarScaling` but not on `AvatarBase`. I don't think returning an interface type will buy you much in this case because the only things that interface can implement would be things that all forms of Avatar share, which wouldn't be any different than methods in `AvatarBase`.

Comment: Agreed. I made sure to keep the base types and am typecasting when necessary. My hope was that if I declared avatar as type **AvatarPlatform** inside *CoreEngine2* that I could return that type without having to cast down. But it appears that this is the correct method to use. Thank you for the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Like HotN and Dinko mentioned, it would be best to allow `get avatar()` to return AvatarBase allways and then cast the returned object as the concrete subclass.

Using Dinko's example:

```
public /* abstract */ class CoreEngine
{ 
   public /* abstract */ function get avatar():AvatarBase {}
}

public function CoreEngine1 extends CoreEngine
{
   override public function get avatar():AvatarBase { return new AvatarScaling(); }
}

public function CoreEngine2 extends CoreEngine
{
   override public function get avatar():AvatarBase { return new AvatarPlatform(); }
}

public /* abstract */ class AvatarBase {}

public class AvatarScaling extends AvatarBase 
{ 
   public function someAvatarScalingMethod():void {}
}

public class AvatarPlatform extends AvatarBase 
{ 
   public function someAvatarPlatformMethod():void {}
}
```

To use a method from AvatarScaling, cast the returned object:

```
var c1:CoreEngine1 = new CoreEngine1();
var avatarScaling:AvatarScaling = AvatarScaling(c1.avatar());
avatarScaling.someAvatarScalingMethod();
```

hth

Comment: Thank you for the response. Looks like I will have to use the typecast method.

Comment: That's what you're supposed to do, pretty much.